# Insert into xml column each xml element as a new row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I convert to XML using `FOR XML`, and a table that has an `XML` column

I want to insert each `XML` element as a new row in my table.

Here is a simple example I tried in AdventureWorks database:

```
create table test( xmldat xml)
insert into test d = (select * from Production.Person for xml raw)
```

This of course fills only the first row with the whole xml, but I want for each element to be in separate row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your data by key into rows with subquery:

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Production.Person o
    WHERE o.Id = a.Id
    for xml raw
) AS data
FROM Production.Person a
```